# plotting a point on top of another scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a map of part of Australia, I'm trying to plot a location marker on it and it can't figure out how to do it - I'm new to python. Can anyone see a logical way yo do this
This is what I wrote for the location of my marker :

```
 scarborough = np.array([-21.9, 114.1])
 scarborough

 field_long = scarborough[0]; field_lat= scarborough[1]
 locate_long = field_long
 locate_lat = field_lat

 plt.plot(locate_long,locate_lat, 'o', color='black');
 plt.scatter(locate_long,locate_lat)
```

This is some code for my map

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

norm = FixPointNormalize(sealevel=0,vmax=np.max(z)+5,vmin=np.min(z))

plt.scatter(x,y,1,z, cmap =cut_terrain_map, norm = norm)
cbar = plt.colorbar(label='Elevation above sea level [m]')
cbar.ax.tick_params(size=3,width =1)
cbar.ax.tick_params(which='major',direction='in',bottom=True, top=True, left=False, 
right=True,length=tl*2,width=tw+1,color='k')
cbar.outline.set_linewidth(lw)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you use

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
```

`ax` is the axes that you can use to plot scatter and other features.
You can do

```
ax.scatter(...)
```

followed by

```
ax.plot(...)
```

and

```
cbar = ax.colorbar(...)
```

and finally, you do

```
plt.show()
```

to get the plot done.